# Php Mysqli internal error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mysqli

I've been trying everything for over 4 hours now and pinned down the error to this snippet of code. Can you please tell me what could possibly be wrong here?

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

class Model {

    public $db;
    public $data;
    public $data_item = array();


    public function output(){
      $this->db = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
      $this->data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tbl_restaurants`');
      while($row = $this->data->fetch_assoc()){

            $this->data_item['res_id'] = $row['res_id'];

        }

        return $this->data_item['res_id'];
    }

}
$obj = new Model;
echo $obj->output();
?>
```

Comment: `tbl_restaurants`. Remove the quotes and try.Don't remove first and last quote

Comment: @anantkumarsingh they are not quotes.

Comment: From where you are getting the variables `$db_servername`...? Might be the scope of those variables are the reason.

Comment: To further explain, I'm trying to hopefully implement an MVC using php and mysqli, a fairly simple one actually. at the moment, I'm only trying to run the code above, I've removed everything else just to see what is going on. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Class definition doesn't inherit variables from the global scope (it would seem you are getting the variables $db_* from the included file database.php) so you either need to pass the variable information in to the class somehow (either setting them explicitly as class properties or passing the as function parameters) or you can construct the new mysqli object outside the class and pass the mysqli database object into the class. Or as someone suggested you can also just define the $db_* variables as globals inside a class function to use them from the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$db_servername` is from *database.php*

You need [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for this:

```
public function output(){
    global $db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port;
    $this->db = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
    //...
}
```

A better design would be, to give the database connection as Parameter to the Model:

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming database connection details but not getting from anywhere.

The database is not connecting.

```
$this->db = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
```

Pass it explicitly as:

```
public function output($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port){
```

OR set them as class variables and set it through constructor:

class Model {

```
public $db;
public $data;
public $data_item = array();
public $db_servername;
public $db_username;
public $db_password;
public $db_name;
public $db_port;
```

And get them as:

```
public function output(){
  $this->db = new mysqli($this->db_servername, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name, $db_port);
```

Comment: Can you further explain?
*Edit: Just tried what you said, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

$db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port not defined in the class. Try this:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

class Model {

    public $db;
    public $data;
    public $data_item = array();


    public function output(){
      global $db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port;
      $this->db = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
      $this->data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tbl_restaurants`');
      while($row = $this->data->fetch_assoc()){

            $this->data_item['res_id'] = $row['res_id'];

        }

        return $this->data_item['res_id'];
    }

}
$obj = new Model;
echo $obj->output();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DB details are the issues, you can either global them or you can, instead of using variables, use definitions in database.php

Rather than $db_servername = "localhost"; ETC. you could do:

```
define('DB_SERVERNAME','localhost');
```

And then instead of using $db_servername in the new mysqli( function, you'd do:

```
$this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
```